# QTextObjectInterface with Qml TextEdit (QQuickTextEdit)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtextedit

I registred handler for simple `QTextObjectInterface`, that draws just 10x10 red rectangle.
When i used `QTextEdit` in normal QWidget app, it worked.
When i used `QQuickTextEdit` (TextEdit qml component) in Qt Quick app, it doesn't worked (nothing is drawed, but the rectangle in TextEdit is reserved, because when i change cursor position, i notice that there is something, but just empty space, nothing is drawed.
The `QTextObjectInterface` `intrinsicSize` method is called (that explains why i see there is empty space 10x10), but the `drawObject` method isn't.

I did some research and i found that actually the problem is probably here:

**QQuickTextEdit.cpp from Qt 5.3.0 sources (line 1821)**

```
QSGNode *QQuickTextEdit::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *updatePaintNodeData) {
.
.
.
if (textFrame->firstPosition() > textFrame->lastPosition()
        && textFrame->frameFormat().position() != QTextFrameFormat::InFlow) {
    updateNodeTransform(node, d->document->documentLayout()->frameBoundingRect(textFrame).topLeft());
    const int pos = textFrame->firstPosition() - 1;
    ProtectedLayoutAccessor *a = static_cast<ProtectedLayoutAccessor *>(d->document->documentLayout());
    QTextCharFormat format = a->formatAccessor(pos);
    QTextBlock block = textFrame->firstCursorPosition().block();
    node->m_engine->setCurrentLine(block.layout()->lineForTextPosition(pos - block.position()));
    node->m_engine->addTextObject(QPointF(0, 0), format, QQuickTextNodeEngine::Unselected, d->document,
                                  pos, textFrame->frameFormat().position());
    nodeStart = pos;
}
```

it never reaches the point where `node->m_engine->addTextObject` is called.
It is because 
this part of `if` condition `textFrame->firstPosition() > textFrame->lastPosition()` is evaluated to `false`.
I tried `std::cout` the `firstPostion` and the `lastPosition` when i established the context and `firstPosition` is `0`, `lastPosition` is `1`.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QQuickTextDocument>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextBlock>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QAbstractTextDocumentLayout>
#include <QTextCharFormat>
#include "qmlcomponentspace.h"
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QTextDocument * doc = engine.rootObjects().first()->findChild<QObject *>("editor")->property("textDocument").value<QQuickTextDocument *>()->textDocument();

    QTextCursor cur(doc);

    int objectType = QTextFormat::UserObject + 1000;

    QmlComponentSpace * component = new QmlComponentSpace();

    doc->documentLayout()->registerHandler(objectType, component);

    QTextCharFormat fmt;
    fmt.setObjectType(objectType);
    fmt.setForeground(Qt::red);
    fmt.setBackground(Qt::red);

    cur.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);

    cur.insertText(QString(QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter), fmt);

    std::cout << "FIRST:" << doc->rootFrame()->firstPosition() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "END:" << doc->rootFrame()->lastPosition() << std::endl;

    return app.exec();
}
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says at

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquicktextdocument.html#details

`Warning: The QTextDocument provided is used internally by Qt Quick elements to provide text manipulation primitives. You are not allowed to perform any modification of the internal state of the QTextDocument. If you do, the element in question may stop functioning or crash.`